# How to use FragmentManager in Fragment - Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I followed this tutorial on this site : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-create-google-map-with-marker/ . It works 100 % in MainActivity, but as soon as i move the code to  fragment then i get an error message that says 'Object not set to an instance'. What could be the problem ? Here is my code :

```
public class ViewAlert : Fragment, IOnMapReadyCallback 
{
    View view = null;

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {                    
        view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ViewAlert, container, false);

        try 
        { 
            SetUpMap();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {                   
        }   
        return view;
    }

    private void SetUpMap() 
    {
        if (GMap == null) 
        {
            FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MapFragment>(Resource.Id.googlemap).GetMapAsync(this); 
        }
    }

    public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) 
    {
        this.GMap = googleMap;
        GMap.UiSettings.ZoomControlsEnabled = true;

        LatLng latlng = new LatLng(Convert.ToDouble(gpsLatitude), Convert.ToDouble(gpsLongitude));
        CameraUpdate camera = CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngZoom(latlng, 15);
        GMap.MoveCamera(camera);

        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                    .SetPosition(latlng)
                    .SetTitle("Chennai");

        GMap.AddMarker(options);        
    }
}
```

The error occurs on this line :

```
 FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MapFragment>(Resource.Id.googlemap).GetMapAsync(this);
```

I tried:

```
view.FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MapFragment>(Resource.Id.googlemap).GetMapAsync(this);
```

But it didn't work.

The map loads without a marker. The breaking code is responsible for putting the marker on the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `MapFragment` is placed inside fragment `ViewAlert`, you have to use the [ChildFragmentManager](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.App.Fragment.ChildFragmentManager/):

```
ChildFragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MapFragment>(Resource.Id.googlemap).GetMapAsync(this);
```